# Setting up integration test project with custom WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I'm trying to setup a test project for my asp.net core web API. There are a couple of specialties I need to handle:

1. Use a different DB for the tests
2. Getting the `UserManger` to seed some users

According to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-webapplicationfactory-1) I should derive form `WebApplicationFactory` and override the `ConfigureWebHost` method. So I did:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    public BeepDbContext Context;
    public UserManager<User> UserMgr;

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            ServiceDescriptor descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<BeepDbContext>));
            if (descriptor != null) services.Remove(descriptor);

            services.AddDbContext<BeepDbContext>(o =>
                o.UseSqlServer("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BeepTest;Trusted_Connection=true;"));

            ServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            using (IServiceScope scope = provider.CreateScope())
            {
                Context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BeepDbContext>();
                Context.Database.Migrate();

                UserMgr = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>(); // <--- fails here
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and this is my test class:

```
public class UserControllerTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory _factory;

    public UserControllerTests(ITestOutputHelper output, CustomWebApplicationFactory factory)
    {
        _output = output;
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Login()
    {
        HttpClient client = _factory.CreateClient();

        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/auth/login", new UserForLoginDto()
        {
            Username = "user",
            Password = "P@ssw0rd"
        });

        _output.WriteLine(result.StatusCode.ToString());
        _output.WriteLine(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

This fails on the line where I try to get the `UserManager` saying that there is no service registered for this type. Also I was unable to make it use the config file from the test project instead of the main project. Hence I hard coded the connection string. After a bit of Debugging I've found out that the `ConfigureServices` method from the `startup` Class is executed after the one in my override. So I think this explains why I can't get the User manager. What I don't understand is, what am I doing wrong or how is this done properly?

As far as I can tell I'm doing pretty much the same as in the Documentation or the [sample app](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/test/integration-tests/samples) they provide in the Documentation.

Comment: To override services, you'll want to just add the test ones to the service collection, and in your actual Startup, use the TryAdd versions of functions to add services. Those won't add them if the test service has already been registered. Some services like the DbContext might require a similar if statement like what you have there to check if one has already been registered.

Comment: If I've understood you right you suggest to do add all services in `startup` with TryAdd so that in test environment the services can be added? But this wont solve my issue. I would still not be able to get the UserManager at this point..

Comment: True, it won't help for that :/

Comment: Check out the thread here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7837
I was having the same issue and using the `factory.Server.Host` to create a scope etc. to ultimately get the `UserManager` worked for me.